# "A result was returned when none was expected" exception on JDBCTemplate update execution

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am trying to execute function via postgresql *update()* method, but it throws me an exception - "A result was returned when none was expected".

PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_order(note VARCHAR, created_by BIGINT, service_request BIGINT) 
RETURNS TABLE (service_order integer, note varchar)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO service_order 
  (note, service_request_fk, created_by, so_status_type_fk, price_total, created)
  VALUES (note, service_request, created_by, 1, 0, now());
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

SQL, which i am trying to execute:

```
String sql = "SELECT create_order(?,?,?)";
```

The update function:

```
int id = jdbc.update(sql, new Object[] {order.getNote(), emp.getEmployeeId(), order.getServiceRequestId()});
```

The function must return VOID that means nothing, but it seems to me, that it returns table without rows, which JDBCTemplate consider as a table.

How can I avoid this exception?

Comment: There is no CALL in 9.6 so it does not work.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-commands.html

Answer (score 2):

As of PostgreSQL 9, there isn't a `CALL` command, so you have to use `SELECT` instead. Calling a stored procedure or function using `SELECT func_name();` will return a `RECORD`. To return columns or a `TABLE`, you must change the syntax to `SELECT * FROM func_name();`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a select statement when you are actually using a stored procedure; you must use Call.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no CALL in 9.6 so it does not work.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-commands.html

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by using `DO` with `PERFORM`:

```
final var sql = "DO $$" +
  " BEGIN" +
  "   PERFORM create_order(:note,:employeeId,:requestId);" +
  " END;" +
  "$$";

entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql)
  .setParameter("note", order.getNote())
  .setParameter("employeeId", emp.getEmployeeId())
  .setParameter("requestId", order.getServiceRequestId())
  .executeUpdate();
```